# 'pyarrow' is not installed - Snowpark stored procedure with Python

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

I have created this basic stored procedure to query a Snowflake table based on a customer id:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_Snowpark_Python_Revenue_2(site_id STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'run'
AS
$$
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import *
def run(session, site_id):
df_rev_tmp = session.table("revenue").select(col("site_id"), col("subscription_id"), col("country_name"), col("product_name"))
df_rev_final = df_rev_tmp.filter(col("site_id") == site_id)
return "SUCCESS"
$$;
```

It works fine but I would like my sproc to return a JSON object for the whole result set. I modified it thusly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_Snowpark_Python_Revenue_3(site_id STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'run'
AS
$$
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import *
def run(session, site_id):
df_rev = session.table("revenue").select(col("site_id"), col("subscription_id"), col("country_name"), col("product_name"))
df_rev_tmp = df_rev.filter(col("site_id") == site_id)
df_rev_final = df_rev_tmp.to_pandas()
df_rev_json = df_rev_final.to_json(orient = 'columns')
return df_rev_json
$$;
```

It compiles without errors but fails at runtime with this error:

```
CALL SP_Snowpark_Python_Revenue_3('dfgerr6223').....
255002: Optional dependency: 'pyarrow' is not installed...
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ask for `pyarrow` as a package:

```
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python', 'pyarrow')
```

But to get these packages, someone in your org will need to approve the Anaconda terms of service, or you'll get the following error:

```
SQL compilation error: Anaconda terms must be accepted by ORGADMIN to use Anaconda 3rd party packages. Please follow the instructions at https://…
```

Someone with ORGADMIN role can follow these steps:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-python.html#getting-started

Comment: Extra discussion on https://www.reddit.com/r/snowflake/comments/yjfykc/snowpark_stored_procedure_with_python/

Comment: That was the issue all along. Thank you! Accepted and voted up.